# Recursive computation with pypsark

Tags: pyspark

I want to be able, within a window, to calculate a sum between two columns and modify the value of a column if this sum becomes odd. Thus, the modification of this column will de facto modify the sum and so on.
However, I don't know how to scan "row by row" my data in an efficient way.
Would you have a tip for that?

I am attaching a few example rows and what I would like to achieve for clarity:
My window will be based on the `ID` column

```
my_data = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1, 0), 
    (1, 0, 0), 
    (1, 0, 1), 
    (1, 0, 0), 
    (1, 0, 1), 
    (1, 0, 0), 
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (1, 0, 1),
    (1, 0, 0), 
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 0, 1),
],
    ['ID','flag_1','flag_2'])
```

Thus my issue is to derive the sum and at the same time to modify the `flag_2` if the sum is becoming odd. `sum` is here the expected results and `flag_2_results` the "cleaned" version of `flag_2` as explained,

```
my_data = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 2), 
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 2), 
    (1, 0, 1, 0, 2), 
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 2), 
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 3),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 3),
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 4),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 4),
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 5),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 5),
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 6),
    (1, 0, 1, 0, 6),],
    ['ID','flag_1','flag_2', 'flag_2_results', 'sum'])
```

- Raw n°3 : we keep the `flag_2 = 1` as the `sum` was odd.
- Raw n°5 : we do not keep the `flag_2 = 1` as the `sum` was even, thus the `sum` is not changing until `flag_1 = 1`.
- Last raw : we do not keep the `flag_2 = 1` (even if it's the first after a `flag_1 = 1`) because it would lead to an odd cumulative sum

Thank you for your help,

Comment: do you really need the sum ? As I see you data, `flag_2_results=1` when we meet `flag_2=1` for the first time. Nevertheless, you need an ordering column to maintain the order of your line. Otherwise, it cannot be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a posTime column to order my datgaframe. 
I can't take only the first, because I want tot keep the ```flag_2``` only if the cummulative sum of ```flag_1``` & ```flag_2``` is not creating a odd number due to the ```flag_2```

Comment: ok, so first flag 2 after a flag 1, right ?

Comment: yes and no, I updated the example to show you. 
You can have a flag_1 and then another flag_2, thus the sum will became even in the end, and thus afterwards if a flag_2 occured it will lead to an odd cumulative sum

Comment: Yes of course, as explained the line 5 : ```flag 2``` is coming in a period where the cumulative sum is even. 
We do not have restriction to put on ```flag_1```, that's why in the line 13 we take it into account.

My point is to use the ```flag_2``` only if cummulative sum of ```flag_1``` + ```flag_2``` is not becoming odd due to this new ```flag_2=1```. We do not have restriction on ```flag_1```.

Comment: how many lines do you process ? in total ? per ID ? The only solution I can think of is using an UDF but performances will be terrible.

Comment: That's the problem, it's about 100k rows per ID. arround 100M rows per run, otherwise a simple pandas function could do the trick

Comment: What is the volume if you keep only the "Flag1+flag2>0"?

Comment: Oh yes, I see where you want to go, in total it's about 62k, per ID it's ~300 rows where ```flag_1``` or ```flag_2``` are not 0. Thanks for this tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment, you do not have that much lines to process. Then, I'd advice you to use an UDF only on the lines where "flag1+flag2>0" :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W, types as T


df = my_data.groupBy("ID").agg(
    F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col("posTime"), F.col("flag_1"), F.col("flag_2"))).alias(
        "data"
    )
)

schm = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("posTime", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("flag_1", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("flag_2", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("flag_2_result", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("sum", T.IntegerType()),
        ]
    )
)


@F.udf(schm)
def process(data):
    accumulator = 0
    out = []
    data.sort(key=lambda x: x["posTime"])
    for l in data:
        flag_2_result = 0
        accumulator += l["flag_1"]
        if l["flag_2"] and accumulator % 2 == 1:
            accumulator += l["flag_2"]
            flag_2_result = 1
        out.append((l["posTime"], l["flag_1"], l["flag_2"], flag_2_result, accumulator))
    return out


df.select("ID", F.explode(process(F.col("data"))).alias("data")).select(
    "ID", "data.*"
).show()
```

and the result :

```
+---+-------+------+------+-------------+---+                                   
| ID|posTime|flag_1|flag_2|flag_2_result|sum|
+---+-------+------+------+-------------+---+
|  1|      1|     1|     0|            0|  1|
|  1|      2|     0|     0|            0|  1|
|  1|      3|     0|     1|            1|  2|
|  1|      4|     0|     0|            0|  2|
|  1|      5|     0|     1|            0|  2|
|  1|      6|     0|     0|            0|  2|
|  1|      7|     1|     0|            0|  3|
|  1|      8|     0|     0|            0|  3|
|  1|      9|     0|     1|            1|  4|
|  1|     10|     0|     0|            0|  4|
|  1|     11|     1|     0|            0|  5|
|  1|     12|     0|     0|            0|  5|
|  1|     13|     1|     0|            0|  6|
|  1|     14|     0|     1|            0|  6|
+---+-------+------+------+-------------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, and for the tip to reduce the rows quantity only on the problems !!